# Python app IAM service account authentication via Cloud SQL Proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python, google-cloud-sql

### Bug Description

Hi! I'd like to authenticate as a service account to Google Cloud SQL locally using the CloudSQL Proxy.
This is done via a Kubernetes sidecar container pattern with the serviceaccount JSON credentials mounted and in GKE with the workload identity feature.
However whenever I connect to my Cloud SQL postgresql server via the proxy from my app, it still requests a username and password?

My serviceaccount has the following roles: `roles/cloudsql.client`, `roles/cloudsql.instanceUser` and `roles/cloudsql.connect`.
My Cloud SQL database has the IAM permissions flag enabled.

The following does not work and results in the following `psycopg2` error:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

e.g. in Python:

```python
    def getDBConnection(self, dbHost: str, dbPort: int, dbName: str, dbUser: str):
        dbConn = None 
        try:
            dbConn = psycopg2.connect(host=dbHost, port=dbPort, database=dbName, user=dbUser)
            dbConn.execute('SELECT 1')
        except Exception as e:
            ...
        return dbConn
```

I've also tried without `user`.

### Example code (or command)

```yaml
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest
        name: cloudsql-proxy
        command: ['/cloud_sql_proxy', '-instances=xxx:europe-west1:yyy=tcp:3126']

        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            host: '127.0.0.1'
            port: 3126
          failureThreshold: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 3

        env:
        -
          name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /sa.json

        volumeMounts:
        -
          mountPath: /sa.json
          name: sajson
          readOnly: true

        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 0.5Gi
          limits:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 0.5Gi

        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          privileged: false
          runAsNonRoot: true
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop: [all]
          seccompProfile:
            type: RuntimeDefault
```

How should I authenticate to Cloud SQL via the IAM service account that is assigned to my Pod?
I see examples using `username` and `password` authentication but that defeats the point of Workload Identity and IAM service account authentication?

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud SQL's [IAM Database Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authentication) feature to create a database account that can only be accessed by a specific IAM identity. It's compatible with the Cloud SQL Auth proxy, so you can modify your existing setup to use it with Workload Identity.

Comment: Hmm, odd, I am using that feature but it still requests a username and password.

```

resource "google_sql_user" "db_sa" {
    name     = "${split("@", google_service_account.db_sa.email)[0]}@${var.project_id}.iam"
    project  = var.project_id
    instance = google_sql_database_instance.mydb.name
    type     = "CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
}
```

Comment: If you check out the page on how to log in when using the proxy, you'll see you still need to specify the email of the IAM account you want to use (as the username) but you can leave the password blank. You also need to use the `enable-iam-login` flag. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#using_with_the